# How to change format of xticklabel when loaded from table

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have the following code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
  6.3e-05 0.8767984145412976 0.6
  0.000125 12.85965577546382 9.970000000000001
  0.00025 16.95140970189756 13.76
  0.0005 14.61328253838453 12.13
  0.001 21.24630316052836 17.76
  0.002 33.45255040918443 27.81
  0.004 0 17.97
  0.0056 0 0
  0.008 0 0
  0.0112 0 0
  0.016 0 0
  0.0224 0 0
  0.0315 0 0
\end{filecontents}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\pgfplotstableread{testdata.dat}\datatable
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
  ybar=0pt,
  /pgf/bar width=5pt,
  bar cycle list,
  width=6cm,
  height=2cm,
  scale only axis,
  xmajorgrids,
  ymin=0, ymax=100, 
  ymajorgrids,
  tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
  x tick label style={/pgf/number format/sci},
  xticklabels from table={\datatable}{0}
]
  \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y=1]{\datatable};
  \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y=2]{\datatable}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives me this plot

[image]

Now instead of the fixed format for the xticklabels I want the scientific format and want an xtick on every delivered coordinate. How do I achieve this? I tried it with `x tick label style={/pgf/number format/sci}` but that did not help.

**Update:**

To have every xtick I had to use the option `xtick=data`.

Comment: So you are trying to avoid the overlap?

Comment: No that's not the problem, I can use `rotate=90`. I just want the label in the scientific format like 1.25e-4 and so on.

Comment: The key `xticklabels from table` has been introduces for symbolic data, i.e. it does not apply the number printer at all. Might be a feature request. Do you need `xticklabels from table`?

Comment: Yes that would be great to have such a feature

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I would benefit from this feature too.

Answer (score 1):

1 `xtick=data` means the x-axis from data.

2 But `xticklabels from table` means the x-axis format from data.

That is, if you want the legend read from `\datatable`, use first method.

The example from [PGFplots Official website](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) shows the difference in two methods.
The example 323(or in Manual version 1.8 page 302)

```
    xmin=-4.7124, xmax=4.7124,
    xtick={-4.7124,-1.5708,...,10},
    xticklabels={$-\frac{3}{2} \pi$,$-\pi/2$,$\pi/2$,$\frac{3}{2} \pi$},
```

Note that `xtick` refers to values, and `xticklabels` refers to format.

So if I change your code,`xticklabels from table={\datatable}{0}` to `xtick=data`, it's done.
But it is ugly then.

Comment: The idea is that number printing is bypassed when labels are loaded from table. For example, if I had an extra column just for the labels then your solution wouldn't work since xticks and the labels would be different

Comment: Could you explain more about "extra column just for the labels"? I don't get it.

Comment: Add another column to the table starting from 17 to 30 and I want to use it as labels using scientific notation(can be more complicated). Then xtick trick doesn't work. That's why it's a feature request given in the comments.